# Is Axiom of Schema Comprehension related to the Axiom of Regularity when solving Russell's Paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As i was reading the book Introduction to Set Theory by Karel Hrbacek, i encountered the definition of the axiom of schema comprehension given as: $$\forall A \space\exists B \space \forall x \space  (x \in B \iff x \in A \space \land P(x))$$ In the book it says that there are some properties which doesn't define sets, so if my understanding is correct, is the axiom of schema comprehension a way in which we can verify if any property $P(x)$ defines a set?

The axiom talks about the fact that for every set $A$, there is a set $B$ which contains the elements of
$A$ for which $P(x)$ is true, so if any element of $A$ doesn't hold for $P(x)$, we can conclude that such property doesn't define a set.

Let's define a set $A$ which belongs to itself (i.e. $A \in A$), by Russell's Paradox, let's define the property $P(x) \equiv x \notin x$, therefore:

$$(x = A)\implies \forall A \space\exists B \space \forall A \space  (A \in B \iff A \in A \space \land A \notin A) $$

But the last statement is false because both have opposite truth values, therefore the axiom of schema comprehension doesn't hold for the set $A$, so we can say that such a set defined by the property $P(x)$ doesn't exist.

Another question: is because all of this that $A \in A$, is not possible by the axiom of regularity?

Comment: The first half of the sentence that ends with "so if any element of A doesn't hold for P(x), we can conclude that such property doesn't define a set." is correct, but this part has two problems.  First, it is whether $P(x)$ holds for elements of $A$, not whether the element holds for $P(x)$.  Second, if $P(x)$ does not hold for an element of $A$ it just means that element is not an element of the set $B$ that we are defining by separating out the elements of $A$ for which $P(x)$ holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so if my understanding is correct, is the axiom of schema comprehension a way in which we can verify if any property P(x) defines a set?

Yes. The axiom claims that given a set $A$ and a property $P$ (I rather say formula $\varphi$), the following is a set $$\{x\in A:P(x)\}$$

I remark that the case where $P(x)\equiv (x=x)$,
$$\{x:P(x)\}$$ is not a set.

> The axiom talks about the fact that for every set A, there is a set B which contains the elements of A for which P(x) is true, so if any element of A doesn't hold for P(x), we can conclude that such property doesn't define a set.

The first-half of what you said is correct since $B:=\{x\in A:P(x)\}$. The second-half is confusing since $\{x\in A:\neg P(x)\}=: C$ is also a set.

> Let's define a set A which belongs to itself (i.e. $A∈A$), by Russell's Paradox, let's define the property $P(x)≡x∉x$, therefore:
> $$(x=A)⟹∀A ∃B ∀A (A∈B⟺A∈A ∧A∉A)$$
> But the last statement is false because both have opposite truth values, therefore the axiom of schema comprehension doesn't hold for the set A, so we can say that such a set defined by the property P(x) doesn't exist.

I'm going to translate what you wrote. Let $A$ be a set. Assume $A\in A$. Define $P(x)\equiv (x\notin x)$. Observe, by the axiom,
$$∃B ∀x (x∈B⟺x∈A ∧P(x))$$
Recall $A$ is a set. Therefore if $x=A$, then
$$(x∈B⟺x∈A ∧P(x))$$
Observe $x∈A ∧P(x)$ is false.
Conclusion: $A\notin B$.
Incorrect conclusion: [insert what you said]

> Another question: is because all of this that A∈A, is not possible by the axiom of regularity?

No. You could adopt all the axioms of set theory and throw away the regularity axiom, or just forget about that axiom as many mathematicians that aren't worried about the structure of the universe of sets (i.e. non-set-theorists) do. EDIT: I felt this paragraph might be unsatisfactory given the title of your question. I will say more. Russell's paradox is the theorem which states $\{x:x=x\}$ is not a set; it does not exclude the possibility that there are sets $A$ which satisfy $A\in A$. In other words, you could have sets $X$ and $X'$ where $X\notin X$ and $X'\in X'$ until you adopt the Regularity axiom---in which case you would reject the existence of $X'$.

Comment: The conclusion $A\notin B$, basically just means that in the case that $A \in A$, $A$ itself is not going to be in the set $B$, but it doesn't imply that $B$ doesn't exist, so in this way we end up avoiding Russell's Paradox. Would this be a correct interpretation?

Comment: @JuanJose Yes. To summarize, $B$ exists AND $A\notin B$ since $A\in A$. Russell's paradox got avoided in some sense.